# Implication of the area law of the entanglement entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

It is believed that the ground state entanglement entropy for a local gapped Hamiltonian satisfies an area law. That is, if we divide such a system in two parts A and B, then $S(\rho_A)=-Tr\left[\rho_A\log(\rho_A)\right]$ is proportional to the area of the boundary separating A and B, where $\rho_A=Tr_B(\rho_{AB})$ and $\rho_{AB}$ is the ground state density matrix. Does it mean that we can perform unitary operations localized near the boundary and make the ground state a product state of the form $\rho_{AB}^{'}=\rho_A^{'}\times \rho_B^{'}$ ?

Comment: I think the area law says, the entanglement between A,B is concentrated near the boundary and fades away with distance. So local operations near the boundary can reduce the entanglement efficiently but may not necessarily reduce it to 0. It also depends on how you define 'local operation' relative to the correlation range of the system.

Comment: Rigorously? Intuitively? Under additional "typical" assumptions?  Exact area law scaling, or with some corrections (e.g. topological order)?

Comment: I mean, just from the fact that the $S(\rho_A)$  is proportional to the boundary, can we conclude that the ground state can be reduced to product state by applying unitary transformations localized at the boundary ?  If additional qualifications (assumptions) are needed then I already know that the answer is No.

Comment: I found one example where that is not true. It is the "GHZ" state $\psi= 1/\sqrt{2}(0^{\bigotimes N} + 1^{\bigotimes N})$, on an one dimensional lattice with $N$ cites, each having a 2- dimensional Hilbert space associated with them. This state satisfies the area law, but cannot be reduced to a product state by applying unitary transformations near the boundary. However, I think the GHZ state cannot be a ground state of any local Hamiltonian.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee Please use @[user] in your comments if you want others to be notified.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee So there you have your counterexample.  Or is your question about ground states of local Hamiltonians?  Note that for ground states there will typically be a subleading correction to the area law.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I meant ground states of Local Hamiltonians and not topologically ordered. 

P.S. I don't really know the exact definition of topologically ordered states. I assume (from what I read from some papers) that those states have constant negative corrections to the area law. In that case it is clear that they cannot be made into a product state by local unitary transformations. I am still understanding how such states arise from local Hamiltonians although there are plenty of examples in the literature.

Answer (score 2):

we have [recently shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10156) that the area law implies that one can apply a unitary in region A such that after the application of the unitary the state *almost* factorizes between the bulk of the region of A and the rest. 
Bulk of A here means that it contains all of A but a "thickened boundary" of A whose thickness depends on the error that one wants to allow (i.e. the distance to the nearest product state). 
In other words one can approximately localize the information in a region "on its boundary". 
Note however that the unitary in general has to act on the whole region A, since the entanglement between A and its complement is not somehow "localized at the boundary" even if an area law holds. For example, you could have a single EPR pair across the cut, where one half of the EPR pair is deep inside of A and the other half far away from A.

Best,
Henrik

*Single-shot holographic compression from the area law*
Henrik Wilming, Jens Eisert
[arxiv:1809.10156](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10156)